# Property not readable on type java.lang.String when using JSF PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to implement lazy loading data in data table using the demo code in the site

[PrimeFaces Lazy loading](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf)

and I am getting the error

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /table.xhtml @14,49 value="#{car.year}": Property 'year' not readable on type java.lang.String
```

Here is my table.xhtml code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:form id="form">  

<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
              id="carTable" lazy="true">  

    <p:column headerText="Year" sortBy="year" filterBy="#{car.year}">  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Color" sortBy="color" filterBy="#{car.color}">  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

TableBean code

```
@ManagedBean
public class TableBean {  

private LazyDataModel<Car> lazyModel;  

private List<Car> cars;

public TableBean() {
    System.out.println("Girish");
    cars = populateRandomCars(50);
    lazyModel = new LazyCarDataModel(cars);
    lazyModel.setRowCount(10);
}

public LazyDataModel<Car> getLazyModel() {
    return lazyModel;
}

public void setLazyModel(LazyDataModel<Car> lazyModel) {
    this.lazyModel = lazyModel;
}

public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}

private List<Car> populateRandomCars( int size) {
    List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
    Car car = null;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        car = new Car();
        car.setColor("color "+i);
        car.setYear(""+i);
        list.add(car);  
    }

    return list;
}  
}
```

Car code

```
class Car {
private String year;
private String color;



public String getYear() {
    return year;
}
public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
}
```

and LazyCarDataModel code

```
public class LazyCarDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Car> {  

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Car> datasource;  

public LazyCarDataModel(List<Car> datasource) {  
    this.datasource = datasource;  
}  

@Override  
public Car getRowData(String rowKey) {  

    return new Car();  
}  

@Override  
public Object getRowKey(Car car) {  
    return car.getYear();  
}  

@Override  
public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {  
    List<Car> data = new ArrayList<Car>();  

    //filter  
    for(Car car : datasource) {  
        boolean match = true;  

        for(Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {  
            try {  
                String filterProperty = it.next();  
                String filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);  
                String fieldValue = String.valueOf(car.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(car));  

                if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue)) {  
                    match = true;  
                }  
                else {  
                    match = false;  
                    break;  
                }  
            } catch(Exception e) {  
                match = false;  
            }   
        }  

        if(match) {  
            data.add(car);  
        }  
    }  


    //rowCount  
    int dataSize = data.size();  
    this.setRowCount(dataSize);  

    //paginate  
    if(dataSize > pageSize) {  
        try {  
            return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);  
        }  
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {  
            return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));  
        }  
    }  
    else {  
        return data;  
    }  
}  
}
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Car class public?

Comment: You have hit right in the head.  I thought I have misunderstood something in Primefaces, but the actual issue lies in core java.  So sad :( Updated car to public and the code works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The model class, in this case `Car` has to be public.

Comment: I was having a similar problem with tabledata tag. thanks

Comment: This was the solution to my problem, and something that could be easily overlooked if you're going over getters, setters, and the syntax in the view.