# mysql jdbc connection no error but doesnt work on the web page

Tags: java, html, mysql, jdbc

I have to do a an web page that is choosing datas from database with jdbc and mysql. There is not look any problem. But page doesnt take the database values from database, it is just shows column name.What can i do to show database values on the table on the web page?

That is my staff class:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 *

 */
public class Staff {
    List <Kisiler> sorguSonucu;

    public List<Kisiler> getSorguSonucu(List<Kisiler> sorguSonucu){
        return sorguSonucu;
    }
    public List<Kisiler> getTablodakiKayitlar()
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        sorguSonucu = new ArrayList<Kisiler>();

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/staff";
            String user = "admin";
            String psw = "admin";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, psw);

            preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM staff");
            resultSet = (ResultSet) preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next()){
                Kisiler kisiler = new Kisiler();
                kisiler.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                kisiler.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("firstName"));
                kisiler.setLastName(resultSet.getString("lastName"));
                kisiler.setTelephone(resultSet.getInt("telephone"));
                kisiler.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
                sorguSonucu.add(kisiler);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Hata meydana geldi.Hata: " + e);
        }

        finally{
            try{
                connection.close();
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Hata meydana geldi.Hata: " + e);
            }
        }

    return sorguSonucu;
            }

}
```

and i have kisiler class

```
class Kisiler {

    private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int telephone;
private String email;

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the firstName
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

/**
 * @param firstName the firstName to set
 */
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

/**
 * @return the lastName
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

/**
 * @param lastName the lastName to set
 */
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

/**
 * @return the telephone
 */
public int getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}

/**
 * @param telephone the telephone to set
 */
public void setTelephone(int telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}

/**
 * @return the email
 */
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

/**
 * @param email the email to set
 */
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

and my html codes:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>View Staff</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>

            <h:dataTable value="#{staff.tablodakikayitlar}" var="kayitCekObjesi"
                         >
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        ID
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{kayitCekObjesi.id}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        First Name
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{kayitCekObjesi.firstName}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Last Name
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{kayitCekObjesi.lastName}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Telephone
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{kayitCekObjesi.telephone}"/>
                </h:column>>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        E-mail
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{kayitCekObjesi.email}"/>
                </h:column>>
           </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you named the value of your datatable wrong. Since your method name is: `getTablodakiKayitlar` you should call it `value="#{staff.tablodakiKayitlar}"` Try it if it works I will add as an answer. CamelCase really matters

Comment: thanks for comment but it is still does not work, table is like that http://i.hizliresim.com/6n7XNW.png

Comment: So have you check if there are actually data in your database table? add `System.out.println()` after the while that fill it and see what appears on the console. If the list is empty, also I just noted other problem: there are few mistakes on your columns `</h:column>>` see the double `>` ? this could be causing the error.

Comment: i did all of them now i get a error "/index.xhtml @18,65 value="#{kayitCekObjesi.id}": Property 'id' not readable on type Kisiler"  and i added kisiler class, too at mey main message

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your class `Kisiler` I would try to remove that column from the page to see if the error is only with the ID, if not it may be because of wrong update of your container (tomcat, jetty or whatever you are using) Try cleaning the code (if eclipse, project clean) also clean your container right button on it, clean

Comment: thank you, mistake  was about "public" at the kisiler class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first please check value from Database is actually return or not by debugging .If you see value actually return ;then check kisiler class have  getter method for those attribute 'id;firstName;.lastName in kisiler class.please check there are getter methods for those attribute in kisiler class.

Comment: now i get a error "/index.xhtml @18,65 value="#{kayitCekObjesi.id}": Property 'id' not readable on type Kisiler" and i added kisiler class, too at the my main message

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887122/property-not-readable-on-type-java-lang-string-when-using-jsf-primefaces  .please see this link.your kisiler class need to be public.